# Not able to perform a search using multiple parameters in ajax and php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search

I have 2 table teacher and teacher_skill whose structure is like this

Teacher

```
id  name  age  rate     skill     loc   exp   avail
1    A    30    2       a,b,c     ABC    4    Immediate
2    B    25    4       a,d       DEF    6    Notice  
3    C    35    2       d         ABC    4    Immediate
4    D    28    1       a,f,b     DEF    6    Notice
```

Using ajax I am submitting the values to the backend where i get the data like this

```
$data = array(
  'min' => $this->input->post('min'),
  'max'=>$this->input->post('max'),
  'loc'=>$this->input->post('loc'),
  'skill'=>$this->input->post('skill'),
  'exp' => $this->input->post('exp'),
  'avail'=>$this->input->post('avail')
);
```

At the frontend, the user can enter all the values or any combination of values or even any one of these values.

> min, max,loc,exp, avail will have a single value from user
>
> skill will have multiple values separated with a comma

I have a basic query something like this

```
  $query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE  %$min% < rate < %$max%  AND skill LIKE '%$skill%' AND  loc LIKE '%$loc%' AND  exp LIKE '%$exp%' AND  avail LIKE '%$avail%' ") ;
```

This is a basic search where all the fields are filled, but I am not able to figure how to use this query for any multiple combinations. The user can put any fields and according to that combination I need to give a search

Can anyone please tell which query would be best for this situation

Comment: What are the possible value for each input? Empty if user didn't fill input and you can have for example "name = A, B, C" ? If you have multiple selection, foreach multiple input the value is "value1, value2,..., value n"?

Answer (score 0):

You should build your query dynamicaly, depenging of filter you have

```
$whereClause = array();
if (strlen($min) > 0) {
    $whereClause[] = "min LIKE '%$min%'";  
}
if (strlen($max) > 0) {
    $whereClause[] = "max LIKE '%$max%'";  
}
...
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE ' . join(' AND ', $whereClause);    
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: will it cover all the combinations of searches?

Answer (score 0):

You can build your query like this I think :

1/ Get your data

```
$data = array(
    'min' => $this->input->post('min'),
    'max'=>$this->input->post('max'),
    'loc'=>$this->input->post('loc'),
    'exp' => $this->input->post('exp'),
    'avail'=>$this->input->post('avail')
);
```

I assume that you can have

- no value `$data['your_data'] = ""`;
- one value `$data['your_data'] = "your_value"`;
- multiple value `$data['your_data'] = "your_value1, your_value2, ..., your_valueN"`

2/ Foreach value, add a condition to your query if need :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE ";

$condition_array = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    // First you check if you value is empty or not
    if ($value !== "") {

        // Then you explode it if user select multiple data
        $value_list = explode(",", $value);

        // Foreach value you get, you will create a list
        $list = "";

        foreach ($value_list as $val) {
            if ($list === "")
                $list = "'" . $val . "'";
            else {
                $list .= ", '" .$val . "'";
            }
        }

    // Then you create your condition where you will search in your list
    $condition_array[] = $key . " IN (". $list .")";
    }
}
```

Then you just need to add your condition to your query :

```
$sql = $sql . join(' AND ', $condition_array);    
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

EG :

```
$data = array(
    'min' => "",
    'max'=> "",
    'loc'=> "ABC",
    'exp' => "4",
    'avail'=>"immediate, notice"
);
```

`$sql` output :

```
"SELECT * FROM teacher 
 WHERE 
     loc IN ('ABC') 
     AND exp IN ('4') 
     AND avail IN ('immediate', ' notice')"
```

Now BECAREFUL : if some input are INTEGER, you will need to remove the `' '` for the list to have `(int1, int2, ..., intN)`. To add some specific condition for some input, juste add a test in the main foreach :

```
if ($key == "your_specific_data_key") { 
    // here you can transform in INTEGER or build your condition as you wish
}
```